# I am not able to Scrape Table content with MIME format of data:application/octet-stream using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, iframe, mime

I am trying to scrape some data from website, but the data is contained in an Iframe. Initially I scraped the source link but from the source also I am not able to scrape the data.
I need help how to extract the data from this source link.
Here is the source link:
https://chartviewer-europublic.bigapis.net/nzgaV/index.html

Also I am sharing the screenshot here showing the download button url of the data under "a" tag but I am not able to extract this link also.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxEgG.png)

Here is the code I have used. I have used BeautifulSoup for the scraping.

```
# Libraries

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Original website link
url_spain_total="https://anfac.com/cifras-clave/matriculaciones-turismos-y-todoterreno/"

page_total=requests.get(url_spain_total).text

soup_spain_total=BeautifulSoup(page_total,"lxml")

print(soup_spain_total.prettify())

# Getting the list of links in the iframe
result_spain=soup_spain_total.find_all("iframe")
result_spain

# Getting the required source link
total_main_link=result_spain[1]["src"]
total_main_link
```

After getting the source link, I am not able to extract the table contents.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you show us your code, what have you tried until now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: From what I could see, that website is not scrapable with requests: there are no apis being accessed by javascript, and the page content is being generated dynamically by javascript, based on some information existent in a script tag. You could attempt to decompile javascript logic, scrape the actual script content from page and recreate the information, or (easier) you could use selenium for this. Let me know if you are open to a solution based on selenium.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire: Thank you for your response. yes I am open to Selenium solution, although it would be good if you could give the solution little from scratch, I tried to use selenium but I could not install the chrome drivers so I left that option earlier. But if you can guide on the initial setup also, I would be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example of how you can get that data using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = ' https://chartviewer-europublic.bigapis.net/nzgaV/index.html'
browser.get(url) 
table = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datatable")))
df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute("outerHTML"))[0]
print(df)
```

This will get the information as a dataframe, and display it in terminal:

|  | Categoría | Ago-22 | Ago-21 | % Variacion | Acumulado 2022 | Acumulado 2021 | % Variacion Acumulado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Gasolina | 22.3402 | 20.0702 | 11311.31 | 231.348 | 279.89 | -17-17.34 |
| 1 | Diesel | 8.9639 | 8.06481 | 11211.15 | 92.9799 | 119.641 | -22-22.29 |
| 2 | Resto | 20.6042 | 19.4492 | 595.94 | 208.715 | 188.782 | 1110.56 |
| 3 | Total combustibles | 51.9075 | 47.5835 | 919.09 | 533.043 | 588.314 | -9-9.39 |
| 4 | Particular | 24.9512 | 26.0833 | -4,3-4.34 | 233.413 | 236.728 | -1-1.4 |
| 5 | Empresa | 21.7122 | 17.6732 | 22922.85 | 224.337 | 215.654 | 44.03 |
| 6 | Alquiler | 5.24452 | 3.82738 | 37037.03 | 75.2928 | 135.931 | -45-44.61 |
| 7 | Total canales | 51.9075 | 47.5835 | 919.09 | 533.043 | 588.314 | -9-9.39 |

The selenium setup is for linux. However, if you would just peruse the questions on Selenium on this forum, you would find countless examples of selenium/chromedriver setups for Windows, if you are using Windows (or for Mac, for that matter).

Also, Selenium documentation is helpful: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer and the link. I have got the result. Just one thing need to confirm, using the Service and option modules are required for only selenium 4 or for all selenium versions?

Comment: @user47341 current version of Selenium is 4.X, and it has certain requirements for setting it up. As far as I can remember, Selenium 3 setup used to be slightly different. This shouldn't be an issue though, as it is advisable to use the latest version of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. just one more question, how can I know if a website is written in javascript or not. Or can I use code to directly get to know if particular webpage or website can be scraped by beautiful soup or selenium?

Comment: @user47341 every website is different in this respect. You need to inspect Dev Tools - Network tab in browser, to see which network calls are made while reloading the page. If you notice an API being accessed to pull data from, you can try and scrape that. Otherwise, you can try scraping the page with requests, and if it doesn't work, you can try with selenium.